# Как изменить цвет для svg?

Tags: css, svg, color

Я не знаю как менять цвет с помощью css для изображения в формате svg.

Источник (изображения): http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/home-web-page_12168#term=home&page=1&position=27

Пробовал так:

```
svg {fill: #008000;}
```

Не получилось почему-то.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все зависит от того как вы его вставляете на страницу, а вообще если по-простому через `src=svg.svg`, то можно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]