# Как изменить цвет svg в img

Tags: html, css, svg

Как изменить цвет svg

```css
img {
    width:50%;
    height: 50%;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<img class="pic" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Dollar_sign_in_circle_cleaned_%28PD_version%29.green.svg">
```

Если я вставлю сам .svg файл в html то это будет занимать 400 over дофига строк кода что не кравиво
Изменять цвет .svg через notepad++ меняя fill= неудобно

Але админы зачем вы классные вопросы закрываете тут есть понятный ответ зачем типа сами делаете хуже
Это не дубликат потому что тут вопрос в том не как изменить цвет .svg а в том как его изменит в img теге
Также тот вопрос не понятный с непонятным ответом

Answer (score 0):

Этот вопрос на на англоязычном StackOverflow [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75572435/how-to-change-svg-color/75572608#75572608)

Изменить цвет на другой [тут](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp)

```css
img {
    width:50%;
    height: 50%;

}
.pic {
    filter: invert(58%) sepia(9%) saturate(11%) hue-rotate(350deg) brightness(101%) contrast(91%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<img class="pic" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Dollar_sign_in_circle_cleaned_%28PD_version%29.green.svg">
```

1. Вместо src="ссылка" - вставь свой путь к .svg файлу
   [image: сюда вставь путь]
2. Скопируй результат с [сайта](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp) и вставь его в css файл
   [image: вставь в css файл]

Comment: А нельзя было просто написать `filter: grayscale(1);`?

Comment: @NNL993 А для других цветов как?

Comment: Никак. `grayscale` нужен для того, чтобы был чёрно-белый фильтр. А чем вас собственно не устраивает сам тег `<svg>`, кроме как "ой, что-то не красиво выглядит"? Потому что очевидно, что `<svg>` лучше, чем `<img src="*.svg">`.

Comment: Много строк кода занимает я вставил там +-110 строк кода (возможно я что-то не то делаю но я просто открыл .svg файл через notepad++ сделал `ctrl+a` `ctrl+c` `ctrl+v`)
А с тем как менять цвет .svg я ещё не разобрался мне через ответ который я написал удобно (буду пользоваться им т.к как по мне это самый простой способ)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143216/discussion-on-answer-by-nevazno-html-css-js-1----svg--img); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: @Nofate и как разместить на чат Stack Overflow на русском?

Comment: Чат уже создан, ссылка "перемещены в чат" выше.

Comment: @ΝNL993 как разместить комментарии на чат Stack Overflow chat

Comment: Речь о системе чатов как таковой. Нельзя перенести комментарии в конкретный чат. Можете закинуть ссылку на чат в https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow-- , если это видится вам целесообразным.

Comment: @Nofate а как ты создал комнату для чата https://prnt.sc/fUMOw7jiahRY

Comment: @Nofate открой вопрос и пометь его как тот который получил ответ и это куда лучше чем то что есть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485092/
тут нормальный ответ на вопрос есть

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143223/discussion-between-nevazno-html-css-js-1-and-nofate).

Answer (score -1):

Я так решаю проблему, но не знаю насколько она вам подойдёт, так как это лишний jquery код замедляющий загрузку страницы.
И в идеале нужно грузить бесцветные svg - обычно они чёрного цвета и на них уже легко накатывать цвет стилями. А на вашей зелёный мешает немного).
Этот скрипт хорошо подходит для проектов, в которых вам нужно создать иконки меняющие цвет при наведении, но при этом которые могут добавляться или меняться через админку контент-менеджером.

```js
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.content img, .menu-list img').each(function () {
            let $img = $(this);
            let imgClass = $img.attr('class');
            let imgURL = $img.attr('src');
            if (imgURL) {
                $.get(imgURL, function (data) {
                    let $svg = $(data).find('svg');
                    if (typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                        $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass + ' replaced-svg');
                    }
                    $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a').attr('style', function (i, style) {
                        return style && style.replace(/enable-background[^;]+;?/g, '');
                    });
                    if (!$svg.attr('viewBox') && $svg.attr('height') && $svg.attr('width')) {
                        $svg.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + $svg.attr('height') + ' ' + $svg.attr('width'));
                    }
                    if ($svg.attr('viewBox') && !$svg.attr('height') && !$svg.attr('width')) {
                        let width = $svg.attr("viewBox").split(' ')[2];
                        let height = $svg.attr("viewBox").split(' ')[3];
                        $svg.attr('width', width);
                        $svg.attr('height', height);
                    }
                    $img.replaceWith($svg);
                }, 'xml');
            }
        });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.content svg {
    width:70px;
}
svg .grn {
  fill: red;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
svg:hover .grn {
  fill: green;
}
.menu-list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu-list svg {
  width: 30px;
}
.menu-list li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<div class="content">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Dollar_sign_in_circle_cleaned_%28PD_version%29.green.svg">
</div>

<ul class="menu-list">
  <li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Dollar_sign_in_circle_cleaned_%28PD_version%29.green.svg">Строка 1</li>
  <li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Dollar_sign_in_circle_cleaned_%28PD_version%29.green.svg">Строка 2</li>
  <li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Dollar_sign_in_circle_cleaned_%28PD_version%29.green.svg">Строка 3</li>
  <li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Dollar_sign_in_circle_cleaned_%28PD_version%29.green.svg">Строка 4</li>
</ul>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: По сути да только я вот ещё js не изучал и мне этот код не понятен
Как это применить для другого цвета и для другого .svg файла?

Comment: Напиши пожалуйста это в свой ответ чтобы и другим было понятно (также *выдели* именно то куда надо вставлять вот этой строке $('.pic').each(function () - Как я понял вместо '.pic' писать в эту строку писать название класса <img class="*pic*" - Я правильно понял?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLO9Fx8tuRs

Comment: @nevazno_html_css_js_1 так понятней?

Comment: Я с js не знаком поэтому нет (я понял только что в js файле написать класс который написан в html и дописать img)

Comment: Ну тогда не парьтесь, используйте по старинке 2 изображения, либо могу посоветовать все svg превратить в шрифтовый стиль на сайте - https://icomoon.io/app/ и использовать. Минус в том, что иконки никто уже не сможет заменить. Нужно будет генерировать новый icomoon фаил для этого.